# How can I define a type for a set of inputs that map to a set of outputs for a function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I would like to do something like the following:

```js
enum Opts {
    One = 'one',
    Two = 'two',
    Three = 'three',
}

interface OneOpts {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}

interface TwoOpts {
    one: string;
    two: string;
}

interface ThreeOpts {
    a: string;
    b: string;
}

interface FunctionResponse<T> {
    id: string;
    href: string;
    options: T;
}

type StartArgs =
    | [Opts.One, OneOpts]
    | [Opts.Two, TwoOpts]
    | [Opts.Three, ThreeOpts]

type FunctionReturn = FunctionResponse<OneOpts | TwoOpts | ThreeOpts>

const start = async (...args: StartArgs): Promise<FunctionReturn> => {
    const [ first, second ] = args
    //...
    const results: FunctionReturn = await new Promise(() => {
        //...
    })

    return results
}

// Current:
start(Opts.One, { foo: 'string', bar: 'another' })
.then((result: TwoOpts) => { // passed :(
    //...
})

// Desired result:
start(Opts.One, { foo: 'string', bar: 'another' })
.then((result: TwoOpts) => { // ERROR
    //...
})
```

Specifically, I want to infer the return type of a function based on the set of input args that was sent to it. What's a good way to do this in TypeScript?

I was able to get the input args to associate properly via the `StartArgs` type. However, if I try to do that for the overall function via something like this:

```js
type myFunc = 
    | (args: [type, type2]): type3
    | (args: [type, type2]): type3
    | (args: [type, type2]): type3
```

In this case, the compiler complains that the `...args` is automatically cast to `any[]`.

[Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYOwrgtgBA8gDgFwM5QN4CgpdiYUC8UA5APa5EA0m2AKgO4kHEIOXVY0AWATsHoUQQ8+bAL7p0ASxAJg3AGYBDAMZ4YueMjTso8kiQBcUJAm7SA5gG4dAI0XcjJsyCvpxUmXKWqo9EppQMbCgyYEdTC2tglkNjCJdrd2lZBRU8Ll5gAO1gxXDnV2CbfMi3CWSvNKgAMTAQZQRJMgAlYCQ4MiRgAB4aAD4c7EkAExKEnWF5McLsEkQmkCQjGkSJBABPODwAZQR7BABBbnMUfB0AHygAbQCAOnVgChwsxCQAXQvru78nvwCP4KXG6vW4ZPi-YQvZAfdAbLY1OoNBatBBgbggJi1eqNFptDqLHoPbKXP6vKAkyEBPoSZSdBBxfZMRRIdb1KAACluXPsJyMu32RxOAEojAAFbgkCCSLrdLFI3Go9EDfADILYWmLelXXSSbgmJ5dDXDKBvJnHJA6AD0lq5tx0GpMUF4SDAABtkEY5TiQCi0RjCIo6IpJPTcHQoOLJdLgOz2UKCKqdMFrbadKIhRJgrxFRjnW7kGV0NaoABhNG8GQGdAmfbsu4PJ6oKB5YhOCyUKDFYiKEAkIRyIhQdPoW79kCxvPu5YMALxlVoKDFuDMrrGgzsq02rluDPFgAibV1wGNk4QVZr3AQdZBDYXLaIbZcHa7RB7fc4A6HGdHH-H7NP07+K8c6qoulpQAAos0zQwM0m6pumQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function overloading for this:

```
interface OneOpts {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
}

interface TwoOpts {
  one: string;
  two: string;
}

interface ThreeOpts {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}

interface FunctionResponse<T> {
  id: string;
  href: string;
  options: T;
}

function start(opts: OneOpts): Promise<FunctionResponse<OneOpts>>;
function start(opts: TwoOpts): Promise<FunctionResponse<TwoOpts>>;
function start(opts: ThreeOpts): Promise<FunctionResponse<ThreeOpts>>;
function start(opts: OneOpts | TwoOpts | ThreeOpts) {
  return Promise.resolve({
    id: "xyz",
    href: "url",
    options: opts
  });
}

start({ foo: "foostring", bar: "barstring" }).then(
  (result: FunctionResponse<OneOpts>) => console.log(result)
);
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIgqgDmAzsgbwChlkYB7cgLmVzClAHMBuE5AIzihroZBaIBfIkVCRYiFABUA7uWx5Cbchh70mrUmDlq+A4aPDR4SZFIAWUCJhz5ipOLo1t2T-qwNjjk5ADEAriAIYMAqAEoQuFgquBAAPFIAfEqkwAAmbgKklhAwmZrI5DihILg0Uh4iMIHBJbRgXGAAFEV4NOg2eACUNAAKUOQAtsCxcQFBIeGR0aXxHQq4iYms1RN1dI0ttuVyCz3I-UMj8eO1U1Ex8bLytksrNZMg9ZutZWY5nbj7h8Ojp48RC6zBIfBZ3IirM5PDZQZqvdoYBbIAA+Zl2thR7ysny6KWQVjA-igTx+xwAdFZcOQADYANwgTXspGQ6RoACIAB4ATwAXmyADRsbJWPLINlE6kCoWFYoxGivNiCLqVIgw5oEMiUdkUci8JgCjhcdmcKB6-hs5BKslgcwQEBNNhNSn+algGj-EqAmajea3XEAXmSCBiNIgZOp5EYTsiLrAXSIyqIQA)